# parC int division rounds up

Tags: c

I came across this code in parC.

[image]

[image]

I can't understand in which scenario (the yellow mark) it can happen?
I mean when does the result of division can **round up** when the value type is **Int**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, integer division for positive operands in C always rounded to floor of the division, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c) for more details. I'm not familiar with parC, but it's said to be [full C++ language](http://parallel.cc/cgi-bin/bfx.cgi/lang_features.html) with some additions from other languages, so described task seems to be incorrect.

If there are concerns left, you always have opportunity to check task directly: setup [environment](http://parallel.cc/cgi-bin/bfx.cgi/download.html) for parC, type implementation of `rsum()` and execute `rsum(A, 1, 5)`.

Answer (score 2):

I know nothing about parC, but as far as C is considered, you're right: integer division of positive values is defined to truncate the fraction, that is to round towards zero.

However, there is another bug in the code: if the array is too long, the midpoint may be calculated incorrectly.

To be precise, if initial `to` is greater by 2 or more than a half of maximum value representable in `int` type (`INT_MAX`), then one of recursive call will get `fr, to` values both greater than (INT_MAX/2) and the expression `(to+fr)` will cause an arithmetic overflow. The result of `(to+fr)/2` will be less than `fr/2`.

To avoid this, expression like `fr + (to - fr)/2` is recommended instead of `(to + fr)/2`.

**EDIT**

There are also bugs in the description! See the image:

[image]

The (4,5) → (4, 5) recursion happens one level earlier than authors indicate, so one subtree should not actually appear in the graph. Additionally, if the program gets stuck in the red-arrow loop, then the (6,5) recursion will never happen – the process will never reach that branch.

Interesting, authors apparently overlooked yet another loop appearing in their drawing;
recursion (1,2) → (1,2) appears even earlier than those two mentioned above:

[image]

As a side note, I can't imagine how they obtained two different results of partitioning the same range:
(4,5) → (4,5) + (6,5) and (4,5) → (4,5) + (5,5)
(see green frames). Possibly they were so absorbed with forcing the idea of up-rounding that they neglected any reasoning about all other aspects of the problem.

Based on this single example I would recommend to put the book in a trash bin.

Answer (score 1):

You might be reading a text which is older than 18 years.
In older versions of the C standard, division with negative operands could get rounded in an implementation-defined way: either downwards or upwards. Meaning that `-3/2` could give you either `-1` or `-2` depending on compiler.

This was recognized as a design flaw in the language and was corrected with the C99 standard. Nowadays, C always uses "truncation towards zero" no matter compiler.

Comment: Interesting version, but figure 2.17 demonstrates endless recursion on positive operands, so it's not the case.